# Error "Visual Basic 9.0 does not support auto-implemented properties" on an interface in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have opened a website project that has previously been developed in Visual Studio 2012 in 2015 RC. The project targets .net 3.5.

I have this interface defined:

```
Public Interface ICurrentStep
    Property outerstep() As String
    Property innerstep() As String
End Interface
```

I get the following build error for each property: "BC36716 Visual Basic 9.0 does not support auto-implemented properties."

I don't understand why Visual Studio 2012 is perfectly happy with this but 2015 is not. The website works fine under .net 3.5 in both xcopy and published versions.

I also don't understand how would I define the interface any other way. Could this be a 2015/Roslyn bug?

Targeting .net 4.0 does remove the problem but that's not an option for deployment at the moment due to some external dependencies. I presume that's because behind the scenes it's targeting a different compiler as per [Is it possible to force Visual Studio 2010 to use Visual Basic 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630426/is-it-possible-to-force-visual-studio-2010-to-use-visual-basic-10)

Comment: As soon as I place that code in a VB project I get errors "BC30273 'Public' is not valid on an interface property declaration"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry - pasted one of the code variations I was trying to fix it with. Edited.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this until I placed the code within the `App_Code` folder of a website - is that the same for you? I also have an expanded example which makes me think that this is a Roslyn bug. (If you add ` = "Hello"` to one of your properties, we get the additional error "Expanded Properties cannot be initialized." - so the compiler believes two different and contradictory things about these properties - that they're auto implemented and they're expanded)

Comment: Yes this is in a sub-folder of App_Code. I think my best course of action is to pull them out into another assembly. I'll give that a go...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Cheers mate, that does indeed work around the problem. I'll gladly award you the rep if you want to put it forward as a answer.

Comment: I 'sent a frown' to the VS team, hopefully they will be able to correct this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does indeed appear to be a bug in the Roslyn compiler. The compiler is running in an odd mode where its checking (but not really compiling) the code within `App_Code` - that code actually gets compiled when the site starts up.

Since it knows that you've set the code to run under v3.5, it assumes that the code will actually be compiled by the "v2.0" compiler, so it's effectively running the check/compile as if you've specified the [`/langversion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd547577(v=vs.100).aspx) flag as 9.

So, that's why the error message is talking about things not supported by Visual Basic 9. However, if you compile the code with real VB9 compiler, it of course compiles fine.

As evidence that the compiler is rather confused, I changed your sample to:

```
Public Interface ICurrentStep
    Property outerstep() As String = "Hello"
    Property innerstep() As String
End Interface
```

This should produce an error about not being allowed an initializer in an interface. However, instead of just two error messages stating "Visual Basic 9.0 does not support auto-implemented properties." we *also* get the error "Expanded Properties cannot be initialized.". But, this does not [make sense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx):

> there are situations in which you cannot use an auto-implemented property and must instead use standard, or expanded, property syntax.

That is, a single property can *either* be auto-implemented or expanded.

---

My recommendation would be to move as much code as possible out of `App_Code` - either just outside of it or into a different library. This will then mean that the code is actually compiled by the Roslyn compiler directly (and without the `/langversion` setting) and that you can actually start making using of modern VB features (you can still target v3.5 but use later *language* features)

In the alternative, you can leave the code in `App_Code` and choose to ignore the errors. If it's just two errors, that may be feasible in the short term.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, using VS2015 Community, the real problem was a blank line between the property header and the `Get` method. See my screenshots below:

Before: ([Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJdQy.png))

[image]

After: ([No error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08L4J.png))

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer saved me some time today!

Comment: This was my issue, too.  While the VS2012 compiler itself didn't have a problem with extra whitespace (or comments, or attributes) preceding the `Get`, the VS2015 compiler (Roslyn) makes it an issue when LangVersion is set to 11 (VS2012).

Comment: In my case there was a comment, but I deleted the whole line as well and everything went fine.

Answer (score 5):

I have a project that is in the process of moving to use VS2015 from VS2008. We need to support both environments in the short term so I have created VS015 .vbproj files that include the directive 
9
in the PropertyGroup section of the file.

I was getting this error because there was a comment between the Property declaration and the Get clause.
For example

```
Private ReadOnly Property MemberNode() As XmlNode</br>
    ' This is the only place which locates the objMember node
    Get
        Return CreatePathAndNode(mnodMessage, "objData/colMember/objMember")
    End Get 
End Property
```

Moving the comment before the "Private Readonly" line removed the compiler error in VS2015.

Comment: I had this error and I didn't have a comment but a blank line and removing that solved the error. Yes, very strange. Must be something with the parser.

Comment: Moving the comment to the end of the preceding line, while making a long line, also fixes the error.

Answer (score 2):

This may seems trivial and OT, but if you're using Visual Studio Community 2015 and you're targeting .net 3.5 make sure the line continuation "_" has not been automatically removed.

VSC 2015 automatically removes the line continuation upon edit and there's no way to reinsert it back (I had to do it outside of VSC 2015). Furthermore the compiler gives you an error on that line but the editor does not underline it.

Comment: It's possible to preserve VB line continuations "_" by disabling pretty listing in Visual Studio, which comes with the trade-off of manually having to format code. From VS 2015: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced, and uncheck "Pretty listing (reformatting) of code"

Answer (score 1):

In my case (VS2015, ASP.NET app, VB.NET, .NET 4.6) I've solved it by removing the space between the procedure declaration and the Get.
The snippet below raises the "Visual Basic 12.0 does Not support ReadOnly auto-implemented properties."

```
Public ReadOnly Property TestProp() As Integer

    Get
        Return 0
    End Get
End Property
```

The snippet below does not.

```
Public ReadOnly Property TestProp() As Integer
    Get
        Return 0
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Interface ICurrentStep
    Private _outerstep As String
    Property outerstep() As String
        Get
            Return _outerstep
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _outerstep = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Interface
```

Comment: Would be better to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to upgrade the the .NET framework. It was on 2.0 and i upgraded it 4.0 after which i was able to add the assembly reference for

and the errors went away