# "Visual Basic 10.0 does not support readonly auto-implemented properties" error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I've inherited a VB.NET Web Site project that targets version 4 of the .NET framework which includes the following line:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Foo(Optional ByVal MyShort As Short = -1, Optional ByVal MyBool As Boolean = True) As String
     Get
         'logic
         return Bar
     End Get
End Property
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and can't build the project with that line in place because the I'm getting the error "Visual Basic 10.0 does not support readonly auto-implemented properties".

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160603/error-visual-basic-9-0-does-not-support-auto-implemented-properties-on-an-inte) that describes an error "VB 9 does not support auto-implemented properties" and points to a bug in the Roslyn compiler and suggests moving as much as possible outside of App_Code to avoid the issue.

Has anyone run into this error and found a relatively painless way around it?

I've considered making the case for changing the property into a function because that seems logical when it's a readonly property with internal logic that takes optional arguments; in this case I don't know that it will be permissible to move anything out of App_Code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that bug, nor how to bypass it, but the question of changing this property to a method makes sense.

The question I would ask is: "Should this property be a method in the first place?"

[Here is some reading about that question.](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/08/01/choose-between-methods-and-properties.aspx)

Besides that, you always can turn a property to a method, but you'll loose some capabilities ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589475/5897829))